# ftp_put in php works only to the root not to sub fulders

Tags: php

I am trying to move images from one server to the other, using  ftp_put like this

```
$des = "example.com/images/";
if (ftp_put($new_ftp, $des, $src, FTP_BINARY))
```

But I am getting this error..
Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Can't open that file: : No such file or directory!

However when setting the destination on the root it does works.

```
$des = "example.com"; //works
$des = "example.com/images"; //Does NOT work
```

Any Idea why?

Comment: did you check directory permissions? and maybe the path is incorrect..

Answer (score 2):

if it is a directory, check whether it exists and put a / after the name:

```
$des = "example.com/images/";
```

if the dir wouldn't exist, the sent file would have been named "images"

if it has a slash at the end, it tries to open it as a directory.

The message "No such file or directory!" is the hint: images/ doesn't exist and ftp will not create that for you automatically:

```
ftp_mkdir ( $new_ftp, $des ); // ignore errors?
```

Comment: I tried the ftp_mkdir  and I got the same error cant make a directory. in the end it was that sometimes it is good to skip the root and just leave the dir

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

it should be

```
   $des = "/images/";
```

since the root is specified at the connection.